# Are all algebraic numbers solutions to polynomials with nonnegative rational coefficients?

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Definition of an algebraic number $x$ is as follows:
$\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\exists c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i=0$.

What I am trying to figure out is the following more stringent definition: $\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\exists c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ **and** $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n\ge0$  such that $\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i=0$.

Do all algebraic number still satisfy the property if we limit the coefficients of the polynomial to **nonnegative** rational numbers?

Trivially, a positive real number will not satisfy the property. So, it is possible to more precisely characterize all such algebraic complex number with nonzero imaginary part?

Comment: Definitely not. Consider what happens when $x>0$.

Comment: Positive algebraic numbers are, as @Wojowu pointed out, counterexamples, and therefore so are all their conjugates over $\mathbb Q$. I recall being told that these are the only counterexamples, but that claim comes with no guarantee (at least no guarantee from me).